# Mongoose OR schema validation

Tags: node.js, mongodb, validation, mongoose, schema

I have a field which will be one of two objects (either a stored credit card or a given credit card):

```
  payment_method:
    cc_token: String
    security_code: String
  payment_method:
    number: String
    security_code: String
    expiration_month: Number
    expiration_year: Number
    billing_address: 
      _type: String
      first_name: String 
      last_name: String
      address_line1: String
      address_line2: String
      zip_code: String
      city: String 
      state: String
      phone_number: String
```

I know the passed data is going to match one of these, but not both. Is there a way of specifying some sort of OR construct for the validation?

Comment: How is the data "passed?" How do you determine which is which at runtime?

Answer (score 1):

You didn't provide examples of your containing schema, but, there are a number of ways to validate.

One thing I did was specified the "mixed" type for the Schema allowing any type to be used for the field that could contain either type.

```
function validatePaymentMethod(value) {
  if (!value) { return false; }
  // put some logic that checks for valid types here...
  if (value.cc_token && value.billing_address) { 
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}

var OrderSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
   payment_method : { type:  mongoose.Schema.Types.Mixed, 
                  validate: [validatePaymentMethod, 'Not valid payment method'] }
});

var Order = mongoose.model("Order", OrderSchema);
var o = new Order();
o.payment_method = { cc_token: 'abc', billing_address: 'Street' };
o.validate(function(err) {
   console.log(err);
});
```

The others are documented [here](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schematype_SchemaType-validate).